# Utilizing perl to manipulate csv/semicolon data

Tags: perl, csv, awk

I am looking for suggestions on how to manipulate data where a 1 line AWK command is no longer sufficient.  I am working with data sets of up to 1000+ rows & columns.  I am running into problems with defining too many column variables.  I am thinking there is a way to use a loop to iterate over an array to possibly define the columns I am looking to count & sum.  I am trying to come up with counts & sums of the rows based on key values similar to Excel COUNTIF & SUMIF.

```
Data Set Example:
Store_Location;Person;Adult_Child;Age;Weight...
LocationA;PersonA;0;50;200
LocationB;PersonB;1;10;100
LocationA;PersonC;1;12;90
LocationA;PersonA;0;50;200

Desired Output: (delimiter is not important)
Store_Location;Count_Of_Adults;Count_of_Children;Sum_of_Age;Sum_of_Weight
LocationA;2;1;112;490
LocationB;0;1;10;100
```

This is an example AWK script that I was using:

```
BEGIN {FS=";"} {print "Store_Location;Count_Of_Adults;Count_of_Children;Sum_of_Age;Sum_of_Weight"}

{
n[$1]++;
C1_[$1] += ($3 == "1" ? 0 : 1);S1_[$1] += $4;column_sum3+=$4
C2_[$1] += ($3 == "0" ? 0 : 1);S2_[$1] += $5;column_sum4+=$5
}
END {
for (i in n) {
  print i,C1_[i],C2_[i],S1_[i],S2_[i]
}
}
```

I used a2p to convert the syntax to perl and made some modifications (based on using different columns):

```
$base = 20;
while (<>){
    @array = split(/$FS/, $_, -1);


    $n{$array[$base]}++;

    $C1_{$array[$base]} += ($array[21] eq '' ? 0 : 1);
    $C2_{$array[$base]} += ($array[34] eq '' ? 0 : 1);
    $column_count1 += ($array[21] eq '' ? 0 : 1);
    $column_count2 += ($array[34] eq '' ? 0 : 1);
    $S1_{$array[$base]} += $array[21];
    $S2_{$array[$base]} += $array[34];
    $column_sum1 += $array[21];
    $column_sum2 += $array[34];
}
@sorted_keys = sort { $a <=> $b} keys %n;
foreach $i (@sorted_keys){
    print $i,$C1_{$i},$C2_{$i},$S1_{$i},$S2_{$i};
```

I would like to be able to do something similar as this, but I was trying to put the columns that I want to sum and the columns that I want to count into different arrays. eg: @sum_array=[1,6,10,15,30] & @count_array = [1,10,20].  And use a loop to create the sum & counts, without having to declare each output column.  I would be okay to just sum and count every column and just print which columns that I need. I ran into difficulty trying to code this in Perl using hashes/arrays.  I attempted to use a hash's but then couldn't get the output format, so I am not sure if this is how i want to structure the data.

```
$n{$array[$base]}{Adult}{count}+= ($array[21] eq 0 ? 0 : 1);
$n{$array[$base]}{Child}{count}+= ($array[21] eq 1 ? 0 : 1);
$n{$array[$base]}{Weight}{sum} += $array[21];
$n{$array[$base]}{Age}{sum}+= $array[34];
```

Edit:
I think my logical problem is that I do not want to call out the field name/column.  Because I want to perform the sum & count over many fields.  The Adult Child comparison was just an example.  I would just like to list the columns that I want to work with in 1 place.  Maybe the simple way to explain it is, lets say there are 100 columns from the input data.  I want to be able to flexibly identify the columns that I want to analyze.  For example: columns 15-30 I want to take the sum & count of each column based on a unique value in column 1.  Then be able to modify that same code to take a sum for columns 15-20 & 30-40.  Using AWK I can call out the columns thatI want to work with ($2,$3,$4,...) but it becomes difficult to manage when there are too many columns.

Comment: whith so much data using database seems like a good idea. Isn't that an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you want and it's certainly not clear what you mean by `"I am running into problems with defining too many column variables" but here's what I think you're trying to do, hopefully it gets you going on the right path:

```
$ cat file
Store_Location;Person;Adult_Child;Age;Weight
LocationA;PersonA;0;50;200
LocationB;PersonB;1;10;100
LocationA;PersonC;1;12;90
LocationA;PersonA;0;50;200

$ cat tst.awk         
BEGIN{ FS=OFS=";" }

NR==1 {
    split($0,nr2nm)
    for (nr=1;nr in nr2nm;nr++) {
        nm2nr[nr2nm[nr]] = nr
    }
    next
}

{
    stores[$nm2nr["Store_Location"]]

    for (nr=3; nr<=NF; nr++) {
        fldName = nr2nm[nr]
        if ( fldName == "Adult_Child" ) {
            fldName = ($nr == 1 ? "Child" : "Adult")
        }
        fldNames[fldName]
        cnt[$nm2nr["Store_Location"],fldName]++
        sum[$nm2nr["Store_Location"],fldName] += $nr
    }
}

END {
    printf "%s", "Store_Location"
    for (fldName in fldNames) {
        printf ";cnt[%s];sum[%s]", fldName, fldName
    }
    print ""
    for (store in stores) {
        printf "%s", store
        for (fldName in fldNames) {
            printf ";%d;%d", cnt[store,fldName], sum[store,fldName]
        }
        print ""
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
Store_Location;cnt[Weight];sum[Weight];cnt[Child];sum[Child];cnt[Adult];sum[Adult];cnt[Age];sum[Age]
LocationA;3;490;1;1;2;0;3;112
LocationB;1;100;1;1;0;0;1;10
```

Comment: I think my logical problem is that I do not want to call out the field name/column.  Because I want to perform the sum & count over many fields.  The Adult Child comparison was just an example.  I would just like to list the columns that I want to work with in 1 place.

Comment: I don't understand. How can you treat some fields (e.g. Adult_Child) totally differently from others without programming the differences? Is it that you want to have, say, an array that maps the field name ("Array_Child") and a given value (0 or 1) to a new output field? That's do-able...

Answer (score 1):

[Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~makamaka/Text-CSV-1.32/lib/Text/CSV.pm) is an excellent tool for parsing and outputting delimited data in Perl. Let's run through a script that uses Text::CSV to solve your problem.

### Set up

Before we can parse anything we need to create a new CSV object and tell it what the delimiter is:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { sep_char => ";", eol => $/ } )
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();
```

We also need to open our input file for reading:

```
open my $fh, "<", "file.csv" or die "Failed to open file for reading: $!";
```

### Set column names

Text::CSV can fetch each row of data as a hashref, with column names as keys. For example, we can read the row

```
LocationA;PersonA;0;50;200
```

into the following Perl data structure:

```
{
    'Age' => '50',
    'Adult_Child' => '0',
    'Person' => 'PersonA',
    'Store_Location' => 'LocationA',
    'Weight' => '200'
}
```

This lets us work with human-readable strings instead of column numbers. To use this feature, we first need to tell the parser what name to use for each column. Since our data includes a header row with column names, we can just use that:

```
$csv->column_names( $csv->getline($fh) );
```

### Specify columns to sum

We only need to compute the sum of certain columns. In your example data, we want to compute totals for the `Age` and `Weight` columns, but not for `Store_Location` or `Adult_Child` (`Adult_Child` is essentially a boolean flag so a simple sum isn't what we want). Let's create an array of column names for which we want to compute the sum:

```
# Use columns 3-4 (zero-indexed)
my @cols_to_sum = @{ [ $csv->column_names() ] }[3..4];
```

If your input has 100 columns and you want to sum only columns 15-20 and 30-40, you can do this:

```
my @cols_to_sum = @{ [ $csv->column_names() ] }[15..20,30..40];
```

This takes an [array slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) of the column names we set in the previous part. Remember that column numbers start at zero.

Once we have our array, we never have to refer to column numbers again. This means that if down the road we want to change the columns we're computing the sum for, we only have to change this one line.

Our input contains the column `Age` but we want the corresponding output column name to be `Sum_of_Age`. We'll put the prefix `Sum_of_` in a variable so we can transform our output later:

```
my $col_prefix = "Sum_of_";
```

### Fetch CSV data

Now we're ready to fetch the data. Since we want to group the results by location, we'll store the computed totals in a hash with locations as keys:

```
my %totals;
while (my $row = $csv->getline_hr($fh)) {
    my $location = $row->{Store_Location};

    # Add numeric columns to the totals, prepending prefix to each key
    foreach my $col (@cols_to_sum) {
        my $col_name = $col_prefix . $col;
        $totals{$location}{$col_name} += $row->{$col};
    }

    # Set counts of adults and children to zero if not set for this location
    $totals{$location}{Count_of_Adults}   //= 0;
    $totals{$location}{Count_of_Children} //= 0;

    # Handle the adult/child flag
    if ($row->{Adult_Child}) {
        $totals{$location}{Count_of_Children}++;
    }
    else {
        $totals{$location}{Count_of_Adults}++;
    }
}
$csv->eof or $csv->error_diag();

close $fh;
```

Note that we have to handle the `Adult_Child` column differently because we are mapping a single input column to two output columns (`Count_of_Adults` and `Count_of_Children`). At the end of this, our `%totals` hash looks like this:

```
{
    'LocationA' => {
        'Count_of_Adults' => 2,
        'Count_of_Children' => 1,
        'Sum_of_Weight' => 490,
        'Sum_of_Age' => 112
    },
    'LocationB' => {
        'Count_of_Adults' => 0,
        'Count_of_Children' => 1,
        'Sum_of_Weight' => 100,
        'Sum_of_Age' => 10
    }
}
```

### Print the results

Now that we've computed all our totals we can output the results. First we need to construct the header row to set the column order:

```
# Construct output header, prepending prefix to each "totals" column
my @header = qw(Store_Location Count_of_Adults Count_of_Children);
push @header, $col_prefix . $_ for @cols_to_sum;
```

We can use the same `Text::CSV` object to print our results to stdout. This way we can use the same semicolon-delimited format as our input file. First we print the header:

```
$csv->print(\*STDOUT, [ @header ]);
```

If you want to print to a file instead of stdout, you can do it like this:

```
open my $fh, ">", "output.csv" or die "Failed to open file for writing: $!";
$csv->print(\*$fh, [ @header ]);
```

We will use the `@header` array to get the totals from our `%totals` hash in the correct column order. However, the `Store_Location` column is special because it is a top-level key in `%totals`. We'll remove it from the `@header` array to make printing our results easier:

```
shift @header;
```

Now we can sort our results by location and print them:

```
foreach my $location (sort keys %totals) {

    # Use a hash slice to put result columns in the same order as the header
    my $row = [ $location, @{ $totals{$location} }{ @header } ];

    $csv->print(\*STDOUT, $row);
}
```

The output is:

```
Store_Location;Count_of_Adults;Count_of_Children;Sum_of_Age;Sum_of_Weight
LocationA;2;1;112;490
LocationB;0;1;10;100
```